# Java Nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet using RestApi and Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, maven

I am very new to Java(of course, know the fundamentals well) and trying to learn Spring, Hibernate and RestAPI and hope to build a website(by following a tutorial from Udemy). When I run the code as Java Application, I get an error which is

> There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
> could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet

The error is actually occurs at line 28 of HibernateCityDal.java file:

```java
    @Override
    @Transactional
    public List<City> getAll() {
        Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
        List<City> cities = session.createQuery("from City", City.class).getResultList(); // error occurs at this statement
        return cities;
    }
```

What to do this to solve the problem? At first, I forgot to pass the second parameter of *createQuery* function, but fixing it doesn't solve my problem whatsoever.

Complete code is below:
pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.akol</groupId>
    <artifactId>layeredarchs</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>layeredarchs</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.30</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

City.java

```java
/**
 * 
 */
package com.akol.layeredarchs.Entities;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

/**
 * @author anilk
 *
 */


@Entity
@Table(name="city")
public class City {
    @Id
    @Column(name="ID")
    private int id;
    
    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name="countryCode")
    private String countryCode;

    @Column(name="district")
    private String district;

    @Column(name="population")
    private int population;
    
    
    public City() {}
    
    public City(int id, String name, String countryCode, String district, int population) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.countryCode = countryCode;
        this.district = district;
        this.population = population;
    }



    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getCountryCode() {
        return countryCode;
    }
    
    public void setCountryCode(String countryCode) {
        this.countryCode = countryCode;
    }
    
    public String getDistrict() {
        return district;
    }
    
    public void setDistrict(String district) {
        this.district = district;
    }
    
    public int getPopulation() {
        return population;
    }
    
    public void setPopulation(int population) {
        this.population = population;
    }
}
```

ICityDal.java

```java
package com.akol.layeredarchs.Business;

import java.util.List;

import com.akol.layeredarchs.Entities.City;

public interface ICityDal {
    List<City> getAll();
    void add(City city);
    void update(City city);
    void delete(City city);
}
```

HibernateCityDal.java

```java
package com.akol.layeredarchs.DataAccess;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import org.hibernate.Session;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.akol.layeredarchs.Entities.City;

@Repository
public class HibernateCityDal implements ICityDal{

    private EntityManager entityManager;
    
    @Autowired
    public HibernateCityDal(EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public List<City> getAll() {
        Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
        List<City> cities = session.createQuery("from City", City.class).getResultList();
        return cities;
    }

    @Override
    public void add(City city) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }

    @Override
    public void update(City city) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(City city) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
    }   
}
```

```java
package com.akol.layeredarchs.Business;

import java.util.List;

import com.akol.layeredarchs.Entities.City;

public interface ICityService {
    List<City> getAll();
    void add(City city);
    void update(City city);
    void delete(City city);
}
```

cityManager.java

```java
package com.akol.layeredarchs.Business;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.akol.layeredarchs.DataAccess.ICityDal;
import com.akol.layeredarchs.Entities.City;

@Service // to denote this is a business layer
public class CityManager implements ICityService{

    private ICityDal cityDal;
    
    @Autowired
    public CityManager(ICityDal cityDal) { 
        this.cityDal = cityDal;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public List<City> getAll() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return this.cityDal.getAll();
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void add(City city) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void update(City city) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void delete(City city) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
    }
}
```

cityController.java

```java
package com.akol.layeredarchs.restApi;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import com.akol.layeredarchs.Entities.City;
import com.akol.layeredarchs.Business.ICityService;

@RestController // to denote it is a RestAPI controller
@RequestMapping("/api") // all operations are starting with api, this is world-wide standard
public class CityController {
    private ICityService cityService;

    @Autowired
    public CityController(ICityService cityService) {
        this.cityService = cityService;
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/cities") // localhost/api/cities
    public List<City> get() {
        return cityService.getAll();
    }   
}
```

BTW, I am using world database. Furthermore, since I am very new to Java, I may have expressed myself wrongly, or I missused some technical things, sorry for that, if so.

EDIT: I thought better to add full error code, because it actually says the what the error is.

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

```
Tue Oct 18 22:23:53 TRT 2022
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:259)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:233)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:551)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:152)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:708)
    at com.akol.layeredarchs.DataAccess.HibernateCityDal$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$69b3ab28.getAll(<generated>)
    at com.akol.layeredarchs.Business.CityManager.getAll(CityManager.java:26)
    at com.akol.layeredarchs.Business.CityManager$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$e6b7371b.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:793)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:708)
    at com.akol.layeredarchs.Business.CityManager$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$73bb0898.getAll(<generated>)
    at com.akol.layeredarchs.restApi.CityController.get(CityController.java:24)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1071)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:964)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:890)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1789)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:63)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:37)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2322)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2075)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2037)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:956)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:357)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2868)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2850)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2682)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2677)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:540)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:400)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:219)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1459)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1649)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1617)
    at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:165)
    at com.akol.layeredarchs.DataAccess.HibernateCityDal.getAll(HibernateCityDal.java:28)
    at com.akol.layeredarchs.DataAccess.HibernateCityDal$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$aa48634b.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:793)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137)
    ... 73 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'city0_.country_code' in 'field list'
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:916)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ClientPreparedStatement.java:972)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:52)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:57)
    ... 96 more
```

It says I think cannot find the column, so I omitted the the countryCode things in `City.java` and it works, I can get an output, but why it cannot find countryCode?

Comment: Looks like you use (hibernate)Session "inappropriate" (hql vs jpql!?). Having spring-data-jpa on board, you don't even need to "touch"(import) entityManager (also not for the "generated method stubs":)

Comment: (official, current) "getting started" guide: https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/

Comment: @xerx593 Actually I was trying to implement multilayered architecture, that's why I have jpa, maybe you are right and as the course advance, your suggestion will be applied and we won't import the entityManager. But for now, my output will be a json file which contains the information of the all Cities in the world database, I think this is restAPI. However, I couldn't solve this problem yet. Thx for your suggestion, but it doesn't give me an insight, or idea.

Comment: @xerx593 I've just found the error, it cannot find the countryCode column, do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Is the column (present) in data base? (If not, that could be an explanation:)

Comment: AFAIK, yeah it is present, and I also copy-paste the name just in case a type may have occured, but still the same :)

Comment: The misunderstanding could also be in: the "db instance" you use... (dev, test, ..., prod ...Might be, that the column is not available on test,..prod?)